# Python : hide mouse pointer

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouse

I am creating a game using the Ursina engine. However, I have my mouse pointer right in the middle... And I don't want to ! Do you have a way to hide it ?

I saw lots of people doing this through Tkinter (which I am familiar with), and Pygame (which I'm not familiar with), but these solutions don't work for me as I'm not using those libraries !

So, I'm searching any way to **hide the mouse pointer as long as the script is running**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cursor() 
mouse.visible = False
```

Comment: Directly into ursina ?

Comment: @Achille G Do you know what library to use for hiding cursor normally outside of Ursina?

Comment: You may be able to do it with pyautogui, i've never done it though